# Information glyphicon (bootstrapmin) inside of Iframe is not viewing properly

Tags: html, css

when the page is scrolled down the glypicon is viewing a text box far from its icon. the html is generated from Scout2 tool and viewed inside of an iframe on my html page. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBxXY.png)

Comment: I don't want to sound defeatist but you need to give us a bit more information than that

Comment: I will try to regenerate the problem .

Comment: This only happens when I zoom in on the page and information box shows away from the icon.